# How do I use Java's MidiSystem.write() function?

Tags: java, sequence, midi, filewriter, out

[Java Doc for Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#write(javax.sound.midi.Sequence,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

I can't seem to figure out how to use this function.  I have a Java.Midi.Sequence and the File I want to write to, but I can't figure out what "int fileType" is.  There are no static int's to reference in either MidiSystem, Sequence, or MidiFileWriter.  Nor does 0 help.

The Error I get when using zero is so:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: seph.reed.effigy.MidiLoader$1 cannot be cast to javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileWriter.writeTrack(StandardMidiFileWriter.java:386)
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileWriter.getFileStream(StandardMidiFileWriter.java:204)
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileWriter.write(StandardMidiFileWriter.java:137)
at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileWriter.write(StandardMidiFileWriter.java:153)
at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.write(MidiSystem.java:1060)
at seph.reed.effigy.MidiLoader.saveClipAs(MidiLoader.java:197)
at seph.reed.effigy.EffigyMenuBar$2.onClick(EffigyMenuBar.java:47)
```

The personal function referenced is:

```
public void saveClipAs(File selectedFile) {
    try {
        Sequence out = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 256);
        Track toMe = out.createTrack();

        Sequencer fromMe = ANCESTOR(Effigy.class).m_gui.getCurrentClip().m_sequencer;
//traverse linked list adding notes to track
        for(MidiEventEntity ptr = fromMe.m_head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.m_next) {
            byte[] midiData = new byte[3];
            midiData[0] = MidiToolBox.NOTE_ON;
            midiData[1] = (byte)ptr.getNote();
            midiData[2] = (byte)127;

            long tick = (long) (256 * ptr.getBeat()); //256 ticks per 1/4 note
            MidiEvent addMe = new MidiEvent(new MidiMessage(midiData) {
                @Override
                public Object clone() {
                    return null;  }
            }, tick);
            toMe.add(addMe);
        }

  //THIS LINE BELOW
        MidiSystem.write(out, 0, selectedFile);
    }
    catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.  I'm utterly at a loss as to what int fileType is really asking for.

EDIT: removed a dumb secondary question.

EDIT: functional code:

```
for(MidiEventEntity ptr = fromMe.m_head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.m_next) {
            byte status = MidiToolBox.NOTE_ON;
            byte note = (byte)ptr.getNote();
            byte velocity = (byte)127;

            long tick = (long) (256 * ptr.getBeat()); //256 ticks per 1/4 note
            ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage(status, note, velocity);
            MidiEvent addMe = new MidiEvent(msg, tick);
            toMe.add(addMe);
        }
```

Comment: wouldn't you know it, the moment I post I realize that that "$1" must mean my new MidiMessage.  Still, I'd like some help figuring out what the fileType argument desires.

Comment: I've found that replacing my inline "new MidiMessage(...) { ...}" with "ShortMessage(...)"  everything is functional.  

Still, if anyone knows where I can find a better substitute for fileType than the magic number 0, I'll consider it a complete answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `int` corresponds to Midi Type 0, Midi Type 1, Midi Type 2 [(more details here)](http://midi-tutor.proboards.com/thread/44/9-midi-file-formats)

In terms of how you go about determining what midi types your system supports it looks like you can call the [MidiSystem.getMidiFileTypes(Sequence sequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#getMidiFileTypes(javax.sound.midi.Sequence)) method.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-providing-MIDI.html :

> There are three standard MIDI file formats, all of which an implementation of the Java Sound API can support: Type 0, Type 1, and Type 2. These file formats differ in their internal representation of the MIDI sequence data in the file, and are appropriate for different kinds of sequences. If an implementation doesn't itself support all three types, a service provider can supply the support for the unimplemented ones. There are also variants of the standard MIDI file formats, some of them proprietary, which similarly could be supported by a third-party vendor.

Thus the fileType is either 0, 1, or 2.
What kinds of file types your implementation supports can be seen via `MidiSystem.getMidiFileTypes()`.
The file type of a midi file can be identified via 
`MidiSystem.getMidiFileFormat()` (see 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiSystem.html#getMidiFileFormat%28java.io.File%29
and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MidiFileFormat.html)